# Regex sub function not working with unicode string

Tags: python, regex, string, unicode, python-2.5

I'm trying to use Python's sub function and I'm having a problem getting it to work.  From the troubleshooting I've been doing I believe it has something to do with the unicode characters in the string.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
import re

someFunction(string):
    string = string.decode('utf-8')
    match = re.search(ur'éé', string)
if match:
    print >> sys.stderr, "It was found"
else:
    print >> sys.stderr, "It was NOT found"

    if isinstance(string, str):
    print >> sys.stderr, 'string is a string object'
elif isinstance(string, unicode):
    print >> sys.stderr, 'string is a unicode object'

    new_string = re.sub(ur'éé', ur'é:', string)
    return new_string

stringNew = 'éégktha'
returnedString = someFunction(stringNew)
print >> sys.stderr, "After printing it: " + returnedString

#At this point in the code string = 'éégktha'
returnString = someFunction(string)
print >> sys.stderr, "After printing it: " + returnedString
```

So I would like 'é:gktha'.  Below is what is printed to the error log when I run this code.

```
It was found
string is a unicode object
é:gktha
It was NOT found
string is a unicode object
éégktha
```

So I'm thinking it must be something with string that is passed into my function.  When I declared is as a unicode string or a string literal and then decode it the pattern is found.  But the pattern is not being found in the string being passed in.  I was thinking my `string = string.decode('utf-8')` statement would convert any string passed into the function and then would would work.

I tried to do this in the python interpreter to work through this and when I declare string as a unicode string it works.

```
string = u'éégktha'
```

So to simulate the function I declared the string and then 'decode' it to and then tried my regex statement and it worked.

```
string = 'éégktha'
newString = string.decode('utf8')
string = re.sub(ur'éé', ur'é:', newString)
print string #é:gktha
```

This web app that works with a lot of unicode characters.  This is Python 2.5 and I've always had a hard time when working with unicode characters.  Any help and knowledge is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The code you pasted should work. Maybe the problem is not here.

Comment: print `string` which is passed to the function.

Comment: updated the question to show that it was printed before it was passed to the function.  I'm pulled the outputs right out of the logs.  Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You should `print` what it returned by `someFunction`.

```
>>> string = 'éégktha'
>>> def someFunction(string):
...     #string = 'éégktha'
...     string = string.decode('utf8')
...     new_string = re.sub(ur'éé', ur'é:', string)
...     return new_string

>>> import re
>>> someFunction(string)
u'\xe9:gktha'
>>> print someFunction(string)
é:gktha
```

Your functions fine. In the simulation you are `print`ing which prints what is returned by `__str__` while when you `return` the interpreter prints what is returned by the `__repr__` of the `new_string`/`newString`.

Comment: thanks again for the help.  i've updated my code so show that I print the string a couple times.